# React Native: Implementing navigation in composite component

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

A react native newbie here.
I have in my App.js following implementation:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <BackgroundHeader
          style={[this.state.tab == 0 ? styles.bg : styles.bg1]}
        />
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
          {this.state.tab == 0 && (
            <HomeScreen/>
          )}
          {this.state.tab == 1 && (
            <SearchScreen/>
          )}
        </ScrollView>
        <BottomTab
          selected={this.state.tab}
          onSelected={
            //(index) => setTab(index)
            index => {
              this.setState({tab: index});
              console.log('DEBUG: App.js: Tab clicked with index: ', index);
            }
          }
        />
      </View>
```

In here I am keeping `BackgroundHeader` and `BottomTab` fixed in my `View` and based on what user clicks in `BottomTab` viz. either `HomeScreen` or `SearchScreen` I just show that component  in `ScrollView`.
So far, it's working as expected.

Now, I want to implement `Navigation` using `@react-native/native` and `@react-native/stack` so that from `SearchScreen` I can come back to `HomeScreen` through keypad `back` button only. (Using a `Button onPress=` and changing `tab` state I can do this, which is not I am looking for).
But not sure, where/how to implement in such case of components nested inside.
Examples, available online are  for simple case of standalone components.
Please help!

Comment: if all you need to do is to move between SearchScreen and HomeScreen, you can pass the function to set the tab state variable right? setting the tab varable to 1 in the HomeScreen will move the user to the SearchScreen vice versa.

Comment: @WenW, Thanks for your reply. Yes, using changing tab state, I can move among tabs. But I am looking for keypad back button navigation.

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Comment: Let me have a look at it.